# extract field only when we have least one registration

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables :

```
author(id_author, date_conf, id_visitor, id_article)
visitor(id_visitor, email, registration_date, registration_fees, ...)
```

I want to extract articles (id_article) when at least one author have done registration (registration fees is not empty or NULL (logically))

For example, when I do `NATURAL INNER JOIN`

```
(id_author, registration_fees, id_article, ...)
(0, 123.1, 1)
(1, NULL, 1)
(2, NULL, 2)
```

It should extract only `id_article` because it has 123.1. Authors of id_article 2 didn't pay registration.

How can I do that please?

Answer (score 1):

I think this does want you want:

```
select id_article
from author a join
     visitor v
     on a.id_visitor = v.id_visitor
where registration_fees is not null
group by id_article
```

Comment: Yes, but can I make `SELECT DISTINCT id_article`? because, it maybe return 2 times id_article and what's the difference between `NATURAL INNER JOIN` and `JOIN .. ON`?

Comment: @Khan . . . The `group by` automatically does the distinct.  Because `select distinct` is really just a subset of `group by` functionality, you should learn that instead of `select distinct`.  The `join` is an explicit join where you include the join keys.  This is the more common and more maintainable version of the join.